# How to create backspace Functionality in swift UI with a swipe Gesture (Same as in original IOS calculator)

Tags: swift, user-interface, calculator, swipe, gesture

I am trying to delete individual digits, swipe over the numbers (left or right, it doesn't matter which direction.) Each swipe will remove another digit until we will reach zero.

Below you may find attached pictures of what I am trying to achieve. Can anyone suggest to me please how to achieve it?

[image: original Entry]

[image: Desired outcome]

Any ideas on How can I achieve this in swift UI?

You may find my code below which is responsible for a displayed string.

```
       import SwiftUI
    struct CalculationState {
        
        var currentNumber: Double = 0
        let characterLimit = 7
        var storedNumber: Double?
        var storedAction: ActionView.Action?
        
        
       mutating func appendNumber(_ number: Double) {
            if number.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 && currentNumber.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 {
                currentNumber = 10 * currentNumber + number
            } else {
                currentNumber = number
            }
        
        }
    }
    
    struct Home: View {
            
        //MARK: - Properties
        @StateObject var viewModel = FetchData()
        @State var state = CalculationState()
        
        
        let characterLimit = 9
        let firstBreakDownDivider = 3
        
        //MARK: - Computed propety
        var displayedString: String {
    
            
            return String(String(format: "%.f", arguments: [state.currentNumber]).prefix(characterLimit))
        }
        
        
        //MARK: - Body
        var body: some View {
        
            //View of Number Pad
            VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 20) {
    //            Spacer()
                
                    Text(displayedString)
                    .font(.system(size: 75))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                    
              .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                                    .onEnded({ value in
                                        if value.translation.width < 0 {
                                            // left
state.currentNumber = Double(displayedString.dropLast()) ?? 0
                                            print("Swiped Left")
                                        }
                                        if value.translation.width > 0 {
                                            // left
state.currentNumber = Double(displayedString.dropLast()) ?? 0
                                            print("Swiped right")
                                        }
                                        
                                    }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try listening on a [`DragGesture`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/draggesture/) on the view where your number is displayed.

To remove digits from the number, an easy way is to convert the number into a String and then call [`dropLast()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893517-droplast) on the String. Afterwards, convert the String back to a number and udpate your View.

Comment: I will update my code now could you take a look and elaborate on what have u ment.

Comment: I have updated my code with a .gesture as per your advice and it worked but the only thing I am facing now is how to keep removing the last number on the displayed string because Droplast() function is not compatible with it shows an error of result of droplast() is unused.

Comment: `dropLast()` returns the modified Substring (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893517-droplast). So you will need to set your displayed number to this substring.

Comment: Documentation which u have attached to my question is just provide a general explanation and i am not sure we have to use a droplast Method.

Comment: I think we have to replace the .onEnded if statement value. 

state.currentNumber = 0 we have to replace this with something that will allow removing the last digit.

Comment: Sorry for doubting in your answer you were right the drop last function after transforming a double into the string and calling a drop last it worked

I will update my code and will leave the answer for people who will need it.